# Amend imagettftext GD to Imagick

Tags: imagemagick

We have a file which adds text to an image.

We need to convert the code from GD to Imagick as we need to add styles and other features which imagettftext cant do.

Can anyone convert the below code to add text via Imagick instead of using the imagettftext?

```
$txt = imagettfbbox($fontsize ,0,$font,$str_l1) ;
$x_img = abs($txt[2] - $txt[0]) + 15;
$y_img = abs($txt[7] - $txt[1]) ;

$im_img = imagecreate($x_img, $y_img + 4);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im_img, 229,229,229); 
imagecolortransparent($im_img, $bg); 
imagettftext($im_img, $fontsize, 0, abs($txt[0]) , abs($txt[5]) , $textcolor, $font, $str_l1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot translate your command to Imagick, but I can show you a simple example that uses most of the features of adding text to an image using -annotate in Imagemagick. There are other ways to add text to an image.

See:

https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#gravity
https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#geometry

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php for the Imagick equivalents:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.annotateimage.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setfont.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setfontfamily.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setfontsize.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setfontstretch.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setfontstyle.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setfontweight.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setgravity.php

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.jpg -font ubuntu -fill skyblue -stroke blue -strokewidth 1 -undercolor white -pointsize 36 -gravity south -annotate 0x10+0+20 "TESTING" lena_annotate.jpg
```

```
-font is the font name (your can use the path to the font.suffix as well)
-fill is the color of the font
-stroke is the outline color
-strokewidth is the thickness of the stroke outline
-undercolor is the color to put under the text -- you can leave that off for no underfloor.
-gravity is where the text will be placed in the image (south means at the center of the bottom)
-geometry is the offset from the gravity position
-annotate 0x10+0+20 --- 0x10 means to slant only in y by 10 (if 10x10 it will rotate rather than slant); +0+20 means raise by 20 upwards and shift left/right by 0. If you do not want any slanting, then use 0x0. If you do not want it shifted up, then use +0+0.
"TESTING" is the text you want to use.
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone convert the below code to add text via Imagick instead of using the imagettftext?

Not really. We can help with problems when you get stuck, provide examples, and/or point you to the right documentation. You are still responsible for porting code to match your business requirements.

As @fmw42 correctly pointed out, your task is well documented with plenty of examples. With [imagick](/questions/tagged/imagick) you would create a drawing context to manage styles, and then annotate it to an image.

```php
/**
 * Create a drawing context to control style.
 */
$text = new ImagickDraw();
$text->setFont('Chalkduster');
$text->setFontSize(32);
$text->setFillColor("ORANGE");
$text->setGravity(Imagick::GRAVITY_SOUTH);
/**
 * Apply to image.
 */
$image = new Imagick("wizard:");
$image->annotateImage($text, 0, 0, 0, "Hello World!");
/**
 * Save to disk.
 */
$image->writeImage('output.png');
```

[image: example output]

Comment: `@emcconville` Thanks for converting my ImageMagick code to Imagick.